# Hints for solving this Number Theory problem on divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all positive integers $d$ such that $d$ divides both $n^{2}+1$
and $(n + 1)^{2}+1$ for some integer $n$.

Currently what I am thinking of is like manipulating $n^{2}+1$ and finding out the answer. Please guide me on how to move forward with this problem.

**HINTS ONLY**

Thanks for helping.

Comment: **Hint:** $d$ divides their difference as well !

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to reach at a constant divisible by $d$

If $d$ divides $a,b;d$ must divide $ax+by$ for integers $a,b,x,y$

So, $d$ must divide $1\cdot(n+1)^2+1(-1)\cdot(n^2+1)=2n+1$

So, $d$ must divide $n\cdot(2n+1)+(-2)\cdot(n^2+1)=n-2$

Follow the pattern to find $d$ must divide $5$

Comment: That is more than the hint asked for

Comment: @DevarshRuparelia, Was it more than hint?

Comment: (+1) .. also I think the downvote is a bit harsh in this context !

Comment: You basically showed how to solve the problem, that is more than a hint.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think so but not too much that it can be downvoted.I would say remove the last step and it would be fine.

Comment: @Devarsh Once a post has been made one can always look at the edit history! removing a line at this point is pointless !

Comment: @r9m I didn't think people would read edit history for my question.Anyways I am newbie here you might be right.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, which I think is really helpful in two ways - first it explains why the method works, then it exemplifies it, and then it leaves the final step to be done using the same method, which must be understood to complete the solution.